# Uncaught Typeerror: Cannot set property innerHTML of null

Tags: javascript, html, typeerror

HTML:

```
<span id="test">0</span>
<button onclick="test(test)">Test</button>
```

Javascript:

```
function test(id) {
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = 1;
}
```

Uncaught Typeerror: Cannot set property innerHTML of null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<button onclick="test('test')">Test</button>
```

This will work

A string is wrapped in `''` or `""`